# Fast comparing two pictures using OpenGL or DirectX

Tags: winapi, opengl, image-processing, graphics, cuda

I need to compare 2 pictures and find pixels that are different with specified threshold.
Now I'm doing it just programmatically in for loop, it take about 3 seconds for small 600x400 picture.
I'm wondering if there a way to do it faster using OpenGL, DirectX, CUDA or something like this? So it will use GPU and not just CPU.
Notice that in output I need an array of different pixels, not just boolean value depending on if it same picture or not.

So I looked at source in delphi and it look like this:

```
function TCanvas.GetPixel(X, Y: Integer): TColor;
begin
  RequiredState([csHandleValid]);
  GetPixel := Windows.GetPixel(FHandle, X, Y);
end;
```

Seems like it calls WinAPI function GetPixel() each time. Probably that's why it's so slow.
So now my question is: is there a way to get whole array of pixels via WinAPI? I'm working with a screenshot that have HBITMAP, so it will not be a problem to use it with WinAPI.

Comment: "Now I'm doing it just programmatically in for loop, it take about 3 seconds for small 600x400 picture." In what language? Is this a debug build? An *interpreted* scripting language can probably go faster than that.

Comment: Nicol Bolas, I'm using delphi 7. No, I don't think it's a debug build. Why do you think interpreted language will be faster? I always thought that compiled languages are faster.

Comment: They are (hand waving over performance flame war here :P). Nicol Bolas is (implicitly) suggesting your current code is very unoptimized. You should probably first optimize your CPU version before considering moving to GPU.

Comment: To elaborate, for most simple algorithms and reasonably sized images doing such a delta on the CPU might be faster than loading the images onto the GPU. To go into details, stop using canvas.Pixels[].

Comment: Hm. I'm using canvas.pixels indeed. :D What should I use instead? I tried ScanLine, but it was even slower.

Comment: @user860478: Raw operations on the buffer. Not some abstraction inbetween. Probably all the function calls to access the pixel values is killing your performance.

Comment: Can you give an example of how can I do this? Using WinAPI?

Comment: On CPU, the ScanLine way is the fastest you can get if you need an array of different pixels on the output, because with it you can access directly the bitmap pixels. The GetPixel is the evil much more slower than iterating through the raw bitmap data. If you need a code for Delphi, then ask a question and include what have you tried. I bet we can tune it up ;-)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Since you are using delphi , you can load the images in a [TBitmap](http://docwiki.embarcadero.com/Libraries/en/Vcl.Graphics.TBitmap) and then use the [`ScanLine`](http://docwiki.embarcadero.com/Libraries/en/Vcl.Graphics.TBitmap.ScanLine) property to fast access the pixels of a bitmap.

Answer (score 1):

While it is technically possible to do such image operations using OpenGL or Direct3D this is not what they're meant for. They're drawing APIs.
CUDA or OpenCL would be better suited, but they're total overkill for something as simple as comparing images. Also the upload overhead will have negative impact on performance.

3s for such a simple image operation on a fairly small image means, that you're doing something terribly wrong. I mean: My laptop can do encoding of FullHD video to h264 in realtime, and this is about one of the most complex tasks you can do on images.

Answer (score 1):

Hell yea! you can do it on GPUs using CUDA/OpenCL, rather your case exemplifies the parallelism you can achieve on GPUs. For example in CUDA you'll launch 600x400 threads on GPU that will simultaneously calculate the pixel difference of two images at each point.

In other words the two nested **for loops** of 600 and 400 iteration count will be removed by 240,000 threads on GPU. Thread 0 will calculate the pixel difference at point 0, thread 1 at point 1 and so on. All the threads will theoretically execute in parallel on GPU.

**Shortcoming:**
Although the computation on GPU will be much faster than that on CPU but you also need to first upload the  image data onto GPU memory and the results after computation back to CPU memory. If the overall GPU time (including computation and memory transfers) is less than that of CPU computation time then you have a win.

Comment: That's not how GPUs work. GPUs have shader units and there are never more fragments processed in parallel as there are shader units. On a single buffered OpenGL context, with very complex shaders you can actually see the pixels being written to in blocks.

Comment: I'm referring to CUDA and OpenCL architecture at software level not the OpenGL.

Comment: Even on the software level that's not how CUDA or OpenCL work. Threads a independent sequences of operation. However CUDA and OpenCL are SIMD programming models, i.e. all the cores are ultimately executing the very same instructions in order called a "kernel".

Answer (score 0):

HLSL/GLSL. 
With them you can perform a lot of simultaneous minithreads, which performance by one is low, but it be good for pixel comparsion.